# How can I add localization to JFileChooser for a locale that is not supported by default?

Tags: java, swing, internationalization

The list of supported locales for [*User Interface Translation*](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/locales-137662.html#translation) does not have all the languages I need to support.  How can I add more languages for a `JFileChooser`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In fact it is possible to use properties file to translate standard Swing strings. Just call

```
UIManager.getDefaults().addResourceBundle("com.mypackage.messages");
```

where `com.mypackage.messages` is a fully-qualified bundle base name.

Answer (score 12):

You can change the properties of your JFileChooser like `FileChooser.openButtonText`

```
UIManager.put("FileChooser.acceptAllFileFilterText", "Directorios");
UIManager.put("FileChooser.lookInLabelText", "Localização");
UIManager.put("FileChooser.cancelButtonText", "Cancelar");
UIManager.put("FileChooser.cancelButtonToolTipText", "Cancelar");
UIManager.put("FileChooser.openButtonText", "Adicionar");
UIManager.put("FileChooser.openButtonToolTipText", "Adicionar ficheiro(s)");
UIManager.put("FileChooser.filesOfTypeLabelText", "Tipo");
UIManager.put("FileChooser.fileNameLabelText", "Ficheiro(s)");
UIManager.put("FileChooser.listViewButtonToolTipText", "Lista"); 
UIManager.put("FileChooser.listViewButtonAccessibleName", "Lista"); 
UIManager.put("FileChooser.detailsViewButtonToolTipText", "Detalhes");
UIManager.put("FileChooser.detailsViewButtonAccessibleName", "Detalhes");
UIManager.put("FileChooser.upFolderToolTipText", "Um nível acima"); 
UIManager.put("FileChooser.upFolderAccessibleName", "Um nível acima"); 
UIManager.put("FileChooser.homeFolderToolTipText", "Ambiente de Trabalho"); 
UIManager.put("FileChooser.homeFolderAccessibleName", "Ambiente de Trabalho"); UIManager.put("FileChooser.fileNameHeaderText", "Nome"); 
UIManager.put("FileChooser.fileSizeHeaderText", "Tamanho"); 
UIManager.put("FileChooser.fileTypeHeaderText", "Tipo"); 
UIManager.put("FileChooser.fileDateHeaderText", "Data"); 
UIManager.put("FileChooser.fileAttrHeaderText", "Atributos"); 
UIManager.put("FileChooser.openDialogTitleText","Adicionar Fotos");
UIManager.put("FileChooser.readOnly", Boolean.TRUE);
```

---

**Resources :**

- [Oracle.com - Swing](http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=133076&tstart=41385)

Comment: so, is there any way to put this in a propeties file so the correct locale choosing logic will be performed?  I could add a check in code for the locales I am looking for but I would rather have the jvm choose the right file for me.

Comment: AFAIK, I'm afraid you have to check the locale and set up the new values manually.

Comment: You can subclass JFileChooser, add similar code in static initialization block (required) and then you can export these values to properties just as you always do.

Comment: There is also a way to externalize mnemonics this way but it won't be so easy to find. By the way: in JDK 6 home folder (desktop) comes from OS, so there is no way to translate it (Vista and above will always show you English name)