# Predefined JDialogs in Swing

Tags: java, swing, jdialog

I'm working on a library that will translate all the hard-coded strings in swing.

I have, with some help, managed to find all the strings related to it, so that's a start. However, I have noticed that upon trying to rename a file in `JFileChooser` to a name that was already taken, I get an error dialog saying that I can't do that.

Was this Java, or was it Windows (OS on which the program was ran)?

If it was Java, I'd like to know more about how to customize such a `JDialog`, and if it was Windows, there's not much I can do, especially since the program is supposed to be cross-platform.

Comment: for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: [de de de deja vu ???](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12520992/714968)  and is very look and feel sensitive, by default most important difference is betweens SystemLookAndFeel and on second side is rest of ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the source code of your JDK in the directory you installed it in.

In the openJDK-7 implementation the String you are looking for is defined in the
`package com.sun.swing.internal.plaf.basic.resources` and the file `basic.java`.
The other files in this directory correspond to the different translations:
`basic_de.java`, `basic_es.java`, ..., etc.

There are all the String constants that are used by the Swing classes.

Amongst them:

```
{ "FileChooser.renameErrorFileExists.textAndMnemonic", 
  "Cannot rename {0}: A file with the name you specified already exists. Specify a different file name." },
```

So you will have to find a way to override the Attribute `FileChooser.renameErrorFileExists.textAndMnemonic` to change this dialog.

If you want to translate these strings refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6932717/1453080).

Different Java installations might have different Strings there since these Files are not part of the official Java API.

As far as I can tell these files are not contained in the `src.zip` that is distributed by Oracle.