# Java - Swing Component Localization - Where to find language bundles?

Tags: java, swing, localization, translation, multiple-languages

### Background:

I would like to have translated **JFileChooser** component in my application.

There are tutorials how to do it:

[How can I add localization to JFileChooser for a locale that is not supported by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3671868/how-can-i-add-localization-to-jfilechooser-for-a-locale-that-is-not-supported-by)

https://beradrian.wordpress.com/2007/07/30/internationalization-for-swing-standard-components

However if I understand well, you have to make your own bundle for every language.

I would expect there is some sort of "official translations repository" for the main component like **JFileChooser**, but I'm not able to find anything like it.

### My question is:

**Does anyone know about some official or unofficial collection of the resource bundles for swing components like JFileChooser?**

Answer (score 1):

Not all I need, but can be useful (de, es, fr, it, ja, ko, sv, zh_CN, zh_TW):

https://github.com/samskivert/ikvm-openjdk/tree/master/jdk/src/share/classes/com/sun/java/swing/plaf/windows/resources

+ ([ru](http://read.pudn.com/downloads90/sourcecode/java/341412/Chat%20Client%20Developed%20BY%20Java/com/borland/dbswing/plaf/windows/resources/windows_ru.properties__.htm), [el](http://read.pudn.com/downloads90/sourcecode/java/341412/Chat%20Client%20Developed%20BY%20Java/com/borland/dbswing/plaf/windows/resources/windows_el.properties__.htm), [no](http://read.pudn.com/downloads90/sourcecode/java/341412/Chat%20Client%20Developed%20BY%20Java/com/borland/dbswing/plaf/windows/resources/windows_no.properties__.htm), [tr](http://read.pudn.com/downloads90/sourcecode/java/341412/Chat%20Client%20Developed%20BY%20Java/com/borland/dbswing/plaf/windows/resources/windows_tr.properties__.htm))